# Problems when switching back to an older git branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I was assigned to work on a new feature in my work's repo. I created branch "A", implemented the feature, confirmed that it worked, and committed my changes. A week later after having worked in some other branches, I was tasked to make a change in branch "A".

So I switched back to branch "A" to make the change, but realized that the feature I implemented was broken. How does this happen? I did "git status" and everything is showing fine. (no modified files and on the correct branch)

Comment: What does it mean that the feature is broken? Is a database field missing? Is a piece of configuration that doesn't click? Switching branches might need of other changes in your ecosystem to occur in order to get your working machine in a good known state.

Comment: @hasumedic I don't think details of the feature is relevant in this case, but if it helps: I'm directing the user to a page to print out contents on the screen. The button that the user must click to go to said page gives a 404 error. It didn't do this before.

Comment: I'm not saying that the actual error will be relevant. But you're blindly blaming git for it to stop working when, in fact from what you're saying, it might well be changes on symlinks, web server misconfiguration, if the routing relies somehow on a data storage then it could also be data missing in such storage, etc. Git will not loose changes for the sake of loosing them unless if you tell it to. Did you commit all your previous changes? Did you push? If so, did anyone else modify that branch and pushed more changes on top? Did you rebase at some point discarding commits? Did you reset?